# The right way to calculate the tuples of Permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, notation, convention

I was studying Permutation in a 'Groups' class. They thought me that the multiplication of two tuples $\alpha\beta=(1\,2\,3)(2\,4\,1\,3)$ in $S_5$ is defined as following:

$$ \alpha\beta(1)=\alpha3=1\\
 \alpha\beta(2)=\alpha4=4\\
 \alpha\beta(3)=\alpha2=3\\
    \alpha\beta(4)=\alpha1=2\\
    \alpha\beta(5)=\alpha5=5$$

So we get: $\alpha\beta=(1\,2\,3)(2\,4\,1\,3)=(2\,4)$
But from other books, they calculate from left to right:

$$ (1)\alpha\beta=2\beta=4\\
 (2)\alpha\beta=3\beta=2\\
 (3)\alpha\beta=1\beta=3\\
    (4)\alpha\beta=4\beta=1\\
    (5)\alpha\beta=5\beta=5$$

So we get: $\alpha\beta=(1\,2\,3)(2\,4\,1\,3)=(1\,4)$

I do understand that both ways are not equal but I don't understand when do I use each way. Asked my teacher and he replied that we use it as in first way because we speak about functions so if $fg$ then $f(g(x))$. But then why other books use the second way? Also tried to use Wolfram ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=permutation%20(1%202%203)(2%204%201%203))) and it gave the second result.

Comment: Some write mappings on the right: $x(fg)=(xf)g$ etc.

Comment: As per what I understand, the second is usually considered the standard, although defining $S_5$ with the first operation is totally fine too. But usually, when people say $S_5$, they mean the latter.

Comment: This is just a convention.  The advantage of the first way is that it matches the usual composition of functions ($f \circ g$).  The advantage of the second way is that we can perform the operations left-to-right which is the way most people read.  I find the first way more common, but the second way is used in Sage (and apparently, Mathematica.)

Comment: I use the first way $100\%$ of the time. No paper in my field that I've ever read uses the opposite convention. It's far more natural in my opinion for it to correspond to function composition. I do think it's reasonable to ask, though: why is function composition written that way in the first place?